# Unreachable code in an if statement

Tags: java

```
public class Sorting {
String value;
char[] string;
Node nude;
Node current = nude.getNext();

public Sorting(String value) {
    this.value = value;
    string = value.toCharArray();
    token(string);
}

private void token(char[] string) {
    boolean isNumber = false;
    int trueCoefficient;
    int truePower;
    String temp;
    String coefficient = "";
    String power = "";
    int coefficientSignCounter = 0;
    int coefficientSign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string[i] == '+' || string[i] == '-') {
            for (int j = i; true; j++) {
                if (string[j] == 'i')
                    coefficientSign++;
                if (coefficientSignCounter % 2 != 0)
                    coefficientSign = -1;
                if (Character.isDigit(string[j]))
                    i=j-1;
                    break;
            }

        }

        else if(string[i]=='x')
            trueCoefficient=1;

        else if (Character.isDigit(string[i])) {
            for (int j = i; true; j++)
                if (Character.isDigit(string[j]))
                    coefficient = coefficient
                            + Character.toString(string[j]);
            trueCoefficient = Integer.parseInt(coefficient) * coefficientSign;  //Error: Unreachable code
        }

    }
}
}
```

---

I am not ready with my code but I can't get rid of this error.
    can anybody help? 
    I am trying to do a code that can read a formula and sort it by power using linked list if anyone has more idea I would love to use new ideas 
    Thank you !

Comment: Indentation of `break` suggests that you expect to hit that if `Character.isDigit(string[j])`. You need to surround both statements in braces if you want conditional execution. As it is, loop will never run more than once.

Comment: You will want to enclose ***ALL*** code blocks in curly braces `{}`, even one line if blocks. You have for instance a two line block that is indented as if you think it's enclosed in braces, but it's not. You're shooting yourself in the foot with this.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you surround each block with brackets. I think the break is actually misplaced in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `elseif` condition is unreachable as you have declared `if(condition)` inside a loop
but using `elseif(condition)` outside  the loop

it should be like this

```
for(int i=0;i<someCondition;i++){//start of Block

   if(condition){

    }
    else if(condition){

   }
}  // End of Loop
-------------------->    you put elseif(condition) after this loop
```

Hence getting `Unreachable Code`.

Note : ***elseif()*** condition should be immediately followed up by `if` clause

You will get the error at one more position

```
for (int j = i; true; j++)-----> Infinite Loop 
if (Character.isDigit(string[j]))---> So only this will execute
coefficient = coefficient+ Character.toString(string[j]);
trueCoefficient = Integer.parseInt(coefficient) * coefficientSign;  //Error: Unreachable code
```

Due to Infinite Loop Last statement will never going to be executed thats why Compiler give you unreachable Code Error

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a condition to terminate your last for loop. It is infinite.

Comment: yeah as i said I still didn't finish my code but that error i think has nth to do with the infinite loop.